# Should you avoid using the adjective "conséquent" in the sense of "important"?

Tags: usage

In conversation with my colleague, I said:

> Si ça ne tenait qu’a moi, l'anniversaire de vos 5 ans de mariage aurait droit à des festivités un peu plus **conséquentes** !

I had heard French speakers use "conséquent" like this so many times before that I didn't think twice about using it myself, but one colleague took issue with this usage. Then I did come across a reminder note to that effect on the web too.

Comment: This is very common usage even [if some people don't like it](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/consequent).  [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/cons%C3%A9quent) *Fam. Qui est susceptible de produire de l'effet par sa valeur ou son étendue. Synon. considérable, important.*

Comment: @Laure I agree with you. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Alone-zee *one colleague took issue with this usage* - grammatically speaking or otherwise?

Comment: @guillaume31 Hi. About using "conséquent" with this specific meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Conséquent* est employé comme synonyme de *considérable*, *important* depuis le 18<sup>e</sup> siècle. Cet emploi rencontre de l'opposition depuis longtemps et la polémique sépare encore ceux qui considèrent que l’Académie Française décide de la langue française et ceux qui pensent que l'usage doit faire évoluer la langue.

***Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*** (Alain Rey) :

> Son emploi au sens familier de « considérable » (1780) procède de l'idée de ce qui est susceptible de produire de l'effet par sa valeur et son étendue ; cet emploi négligé, populaire, est condamné par Littré comme un barbarisme, mais n'en est pas moins fréquent.

**[Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/consequent)** :

> employer *Conséquent* pour « important, considérable » ou encore « gros » est un barbarisme contre lequel Littré mettait déjà en garde.

Et pourtant cet emploi de l'adjectif *conséquent* dérive du sens de *conséquence* [signalé par Furetière](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5841680f/f724.item.r=cons%C3%A9quence) (1690) :

> Conséquence signifie aussi grande importance ou considération. C'est un homme de *conséquence*, d'un grand mérite, il a acheté une terre de *conséquence*, c'est-à-dire de grand prix.

Claude Duneton ([*«Conséquent» ou «important»: ne faites plus la faute!*](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/06/23/37003-20170623ARTFIG00014-consequent-ou-important-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php), 23/06/2017) souligne que cette acceptation a même été reprise dans le « dictionnaire de l'Académie française, dont l'édition de 1835 déclarait sans ambages: «Conséquence se prend pour importance», citant les mêmes exemples que Furetière.»

Il est très difficile de faire des recherches sur le mot utilisé  spécifiquement dans ce sens mais on le lit et l'entend tous les jours, pas que sur les marchés mais aussi dans la presse écrite et à la radio. Ensuite, à chacun ses opinions et son style. Ce qu'il faut savoir pour un non francophone c'est que le mot est pour certains socialement marqué, donc pour répondre directement à la question, je dirais que son emploi peut être déterminé par l'image qu'on veut donner de soi, et de la personne à laquelle on s'adresse. Personnellement je trouve l'emploi de *conséquent* au sens de *considérable* tout à fait normal, et je sais que je ne suis pas la seule.

Claude Duneton, dans le billet cité ci-dessus et dont je recommande la lecture in-extenso, nous explique pourquoi cet emploi de l’adjectif *conséquent* est socialement marqué et rappelle l’anecdote suivante pour montrer comment « La grande bourgeoisie post-révolutionnaire du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, composée surtout de parvenus, s'est servie de la langue mondaine comme de l'instrument de son auto-aristocratisation. C'est pourquoi tous les auteurs de dictionnaires, et Littré avec eux, ont répercuté l'anathème contre *conséquent*, sans se soucier de l'arbitraire d'une pareille tradition. »

> Lorsque la jeune et jolie Sophie Gay, femme du monde proche de la cour impériale, après l'avoir été de Marie-Antoinette, fait parler le petit commerce, vers 1805, elle évoque le dialogue suivant, tout à fait réaliste:
>   «Sais-tu bien que tu as là quelque chose de conséquent? dit d'un air coupable un fripier ambulant à son cousin le garçon limonadier. J'en ai vu une épingle, dans ce goût-là, et qui a été vendue plus de 80 francs.» (Salons célèbres.) Voilà le vice rédhibitoire de conséquent, il est dans la bouche d'un fripier! Horreur et damnation! Napoléon Landais, grammairien et lexicographe, est le tout premier à annoncer en 1836: «Quelquefois, en style mercantile, on l'emploie pour important, considérable.» Puis il ajoute avec une assurance stupéfiante: «C'est en ce sens une faute grave.»

Answer (score 1):

À côté du débat étymologique et historique fort bien illustré par Laure, on peut se poser la simple question suivante : que signifie alors le contraire « inconséquent » et que fait-on de la paire « conséquence/inconséquence » ?
À ma connaissance, personne n'emploie inconséquent pour signifier « de faible valeur ». Pourquoi donc alors cautionner l'emploi de l'antonyme avec une notion quantitative au détriment de la cohérence de la langue ? On peut juger cela quelque peu… inconséquent.

Comment: Que penser de *qualifiable* et *inqualifiable*? Et dire d'une boisson qu'elle est *buvable* n'est habituellement pas un compliment, à moins d'utiliser un euphémisme: ce qui est buvable l'est tout juste. Ça rend le concept très proche d'*imbuvable*, qui décrit une boisson que l'on peut habituellement boire sans mourir ou tomber malade, mais que l'on ne désire pas consommer une deuxième fois à cause d'un goût ou d'une texture qui écœure; ou alors, dans une autre acception, qqn ou qqch qui énerve infiniment (et en ce sens absolument dégagé de tout lien avec *buvable*).

Comment: @ Feelew Merci pour votre remarque : les mots formés avec le préfixe in- ne sont en effet pas toujours de purs antonymes. Cela étant, dans le cas d'espèce, conséquent et inconséquent le sont bien : c'est la notion de cohérence et de conséquences qui les réunit. Pourquoi la détruire avec un sens totalement étranger ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas de réponse absolue à votre interrogation, mais du moins une opinion fondée sur des raisons que je puis accepter, tout en sachant que d'autres les accepteront moins (les raisons invoquées par Laure, par exemple, me conviennent et ne vous ont pas convaincu: ainsi soit-il, le français peut et doit être un outil d'expression de toutes les opinions). Dommage pour ceux qui veulent la logique à tout prix, cependant, le français n'est ni un musée, ni une démonstration mathématique, mais une entité vivante utilisée par des gens d'origines diverses et de tous les niveaux sociaux.

Comment: Nous l'avons reçu en l'état où nos ancêtres nous l'ont laissé, imparfaite mais malléable et dynamique, et nous la passerons à nos descendants avec le gros du large fond que nous avons reçu et les quelques ajouts et modifications que nous lui aurons donné. Il y a bien un certain brassage intergénérationnel, mais la vie d'une personne à laquelle on ajoutera celle des gens avec lesquels elle interagira ne couvre guère plus de deux siècles, une fraction de celle de la langue française. Y maintenir l'ordre absolu me semble une chimère, quoiqu'il soit bien que certains y consacrent leur énergie.

Comment: Et malgré une divergence de vues, j'ai plussoyé votre réponse, car elle apporte selon moi un point valide qui se devait d'être présenté: mon opinion n'est pas **indifférente**, elle est simplement **différente**.