# Comment traduire la phrase complète “I struggle” en français, en parlant de ce que quelqu'un fait dans la vie ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, demande-de-mot

Supposons que dans une conversation, on demande à une personne ce qu'elle fait dans la vie. La réponse est « *I struggle* ». Dans le sens, j'ai beaucoup de problèmes dans ma vie personnelle et professionnelle, j'ai beaucoup de doutes et d'inquiétudes à propos des chemins que j'ai choisi, que je dois choisir, ou corriger peut-être, et il me faut donc toujours vivre dans ce contexte qui est l'état normal de ma vie, celui qui est le seul qui laisse la possibilité de faire quelque chose de positif, donc celui dans lequel il est important de toujours être.

Comment, aussi brièvement que possible, traduit-on cette réponse en français ?  Je crois que la traduction standard « je lutte » ne rend pas l'aspect « être assailli de problèmes », en souffrir peut-être ; c'est-à-dire, cette signification qui représente la souffrance comme la caractéristique principale de la vie. Je n'aime pas non plus la traduction « je souffre », parce qu'elle est trop pessimiste…

Comment: Trop vulgaire, j'imagine, donc comme commentaire je dirais que quand je me trouve dans les situations comme celle de votre example, je reponde, soit: "J'en chie [mais c'est bon]!" soit "J'en bave [mais c'est bon]!"

Comment: Evgeniy, j'avoue avoir encore du mal à comprendre ce signifie la fin du premier paragraphe...

Comment: J'ai édité le titre pour ajouter le contexte (ce que quelqu'un fait dans la vie), pour lequel "je galère" me paraît être la meilleure réponse. Autrement, les traductions "j'ai du mal" ou "je lutte" peuvent être appropriées, mais pas dans ce contexte particulier.

Comment: *Valable* n'est alors pas le mot attendu.

Comment: Mais *quelque chose de conséquence* ne veut rien dire, j'ai mis *de positif* qui je pense est le sens attendu...

Comment: (I'm sorry, Eveniy, for steering you in the wrong direction with my suggestion of "de conséquence." I mistakenly assumed that "quelque chose de conséquence" in French would/could mean the same [and be as idiomatic] as "something of consequence" does [and is] in English [i.e., "something important/something meaningful/something significant/something worthwhile/worth doing"], but @jlliagre is correct in saying that it doesn't [and even if it could, I see now that it wouldn't be idiomatic at all in French]. Mea culpa!)

Comment: @PapaPoule My mistake, it looks like the expression existed in older French. In modern one, we usually say *quelque chose de conséquent* meaning something big/sizeable although the Académie française doesn't support this acception. http://www.academie-francaise.fr/consequent See also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/should-you-avoid-using-the-adjective-cons%C3%A9quent-in-the-sense-of-important

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Une traduction possible pourrait être :

> Je galère.

C'est moins pessimiste que "je souffre" (qui est complètement passif).

Comment: c'est aussi ce qui me parait le plus adapté dans cette situation ;)

Comment: Ça me paraît la meilleure expression

Answer (score 5):

Je me débrouille.

C'est encore moins pessimiste.

Answer (score 3):

Une solution régionale (au Québec) à [*to struggle*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/struggle/615532) c'est l'emprunt intégral à l'[anglais...](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/rush) [*to rush*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=rush&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=4408) (dont on connaît plus généralement l'emprunt du substantif un [*rush*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rush_rushs/70288) (ruée) en français<sup>1</sup>), basé sur l'idée du *mouvement rapide* ou de l'*effort violent* :

> Je/j'(e) rush(e) (dans la vie).

Dans un contexte très concret et immédiat, ça signifie pour moi *avoir de la difficulté* mais les notions d'*effort* et de *combat* peuvent être très présentes selon le contexte (par ex. à la BDL : *Lise a rushé pour avoir le poste d’adjointe à la direction.* ; s'est *démenée*). La locution *travailler avec acharnement* est utile, ainsi que les verbes *[bagarrer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bagarrer) (dur)* et [*batailler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/batailler) (vieux Fr., usuel Qc).

Incidemment, l'idée de *se démener* et les explications en question me font aussi penser un *[diable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diable) qui se débat dans l'eau bénite* (un autre genre de [galérien](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29190) pour ainsi dire), légère variation d'une expression connue en français plus régulier, « I. C. 3. par référence aux attributs moraux, aux pouvoirs, aux attitudes que la tradition populaire prête au diable, la notion religieuse étant absente ou peu marquée / c. diable a un contenu intensif ou hyperbolique, parfois valorisant / α. Avec l'idée dominante d'énergie, de vivacité ou de désordre, de complication » (TLFi, *diable* I.C.3.c.α.) ; on peut présenter la locution en illustration : *(je suis) comme...* On a parlé aussi *d'inquiétudes*, de *toujours vivre dans ce contexte*, d'*état normal* etc. et ça m'a fait penser au [*spleen*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/spleen/74273?q=spleen#73440) mélancolique qui se trouve peut-être en périphérie de ce qu'on recherche... J'ai aussi compris indirectement de la question l'idée de s'efforcer de [*faire face à la musique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3610) (Qc. ; la *BDL* le dit peu utile et donne *braver la tempête*...).

---

On peut penser à *je rush(e) (Qc), je bagarre dur, je bataille fort (vieux, Qc), je me démène, je travaille acharnement, j'affronte/je brave la tempête*, entre autres.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On connaît aussi peut-être le surnom de George « Rush » St-Pierre.</sub>

Comment: Le verbe _rusher_ on prononcerait ça comme _rocher_ (et l'exemple en réponse comme _je roche_).